# Average Score for games. Either I divide by zero or calculate one too many

Tags: java, function, average

hey i need some quick advice. i want to calculate average score for game, and update it every round, but i cant do this properly.

```
    private void updateAverage(GLabel average) {
    average.setLabel(String.valueOf("Avg: " 
         + String.valueOf((int)((AI_SCORE + PLAYER_SCORE) / TOTAL_GAMES))));
    average.setLocation(getWidth() / 2 - average.getWidth() / 2,
         getHeight() - PADDING);
    TOTAL_GAMES++;
}
```

this is the code I use. I also call this method before 1st round, to put the counter on screen. If I set `TOTAL_GAMES = 0;` when definig, I get `/ by 0` error. But if I set it at `1`, by average is flawed. I can't find the right place for `TOTAL_GAMES++;`m I tried putting it in method detecting game loss, after upadting average like in code above and some other, but every time the average is calculated wrong.

[Full code here](http://pastebin.com/jjmeZKWc)

Comment: What *is* the average score before the 1st round?

Comment: @Gabe both AI and player scores are `0`, and it's 1st round so i guess it should be `0`.

Comment: Well there's your answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for `TOTAL_GAMES` being == to 0.

```
private void updateAverage(GLabel average) {
 if(TOTAL_GAMES == 0){
    average.setLabel("0");
    return;
  }
average.setLabel(String.valueOf("Avg: " 
     + String.valueOf((int)((AI_SCORE + PLAYER_SCORE) / TOTAL_GAMES))));
average.setLocation(getWidth() / 2 - average.getWidth() / 2,
     getHeight() - PADDING);
TOTAL_GAMES++;
}
```

Comment: This is so simple and I didn't even consider that. I think I should get some sleep.

Comment: @asalas77 Sometimes the answer is just sitting in front of you. It can help to take a minute away from the keyboard and mull over your problem. Anyway, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

the if statement will work from above user.

looks like you are converting the (AI_SCORE + PLAYER_SCORE)/(TOTAL_GAMES) to an int, which will alter the answer.

if total_games is global, that should work just fine. Not sure why it is a float though.